# Android share ListView content

Tags: android, listview, mp3, share

I have many items in my soundboard and i need to share them.I have tried this

```
    private void shareImage(int resId) {

      Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

      // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
      // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
      share.setType("audio/mp3");

      // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
      // directory
      String imagePath = "android.resource://com.example.app/" + resId;

      File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

      Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
      share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
    }
```

but without succes! Thanks

Comment: what was your actual problem? Provide more information

Comment: When i try to share a sound, for example with WhatsApp, it say that it's  impossible!!

Answer (score 0):

Few, if any, Android apps are set up with an `<intent-filter>` that handles the `android.resource` scheme. Either copy the file to internal storage and [use `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), or just [use my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) (which streams resources), to have a `content` `Uri` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the resource path is correct.

Say, if you have an audio in your **res/raw/song.mp3**

then the path should be like this

String path = "android.resource://**PACKAGENAME**/res/" + Integer.toString(R.raw.song);

Example code like this..

```
private void shareAudio(int resId) {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/mp3");
    String path = "android.resource://com.example.app/res/" + Integer.toString(resId);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Audio!"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Use the Uri.fromFile and put your File like this example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
File your_file = new File("your path");
i.setType("plain/text");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(your_file));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Share..."));
```